# How to use my project DLL as a third party DLL in another project

Tags: wpf, dll, .net-assembly

I have one WPF project.In this project I have one project for DataAccess Layer.
My requirement is: I want to use DLL of DataAccess Layer in another projects as third party DLL.How to do that..??

I have created a library project called "MyData".I have added a reference of DataAccess Layer project in that.And then I have used "MyData.dll" in another project.But it is giving me error:
"Could not load file or assembly 'MyData, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=36bcb1fcead6cc72' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified." Any suggestions..?? How to do this..??

Comment: K T - why have you accepted only 4 answers for you 16 questions? And why do you ignore any comments?

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1. Check if your "MyData.dll" is correct referred to and if that file exists.
2. If your "MyData.dll" has any dependencies you have to reference them too in your project you want to use your "MyData.dll"

Comment: Yes there is dependency of "MyData.dll" on other dll.So is it possible to combine that dll with "MyData.dll"...?? so that i can have only one dll to be used as third party dll

Comment: I have downloaded ILMerge to merge my 2 dlls into 1 but I am not getting how to use it.Please help.

Comment: There could be licensing problems if you merge your dll with an other third party dll. I dont know that tool you downloaded.

Comment: it is Microsoft tool called ILMerge